# Customized Enum in Java8

Tags: java, java-8, enums

To clarify my goal I rephrased the question. Here the use-case I am trying to solve: At the moment there are more than 50 tables in my project. At several locations these tables are used(Rendering, TableModel, etc.) The project is quite old and also includes some features which might not be necessary today however that's a different topic. One example where a table is used is this one:

```
exampleTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(50);          
exampleTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(200);        
exampleTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(150);         
exampleTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(100);
```

and in the table model:

```
public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {

    if (columnIndex == 0) {
        return Integer.class;
    } else if (columnIndex == 3) {
        return Date.class;
    }
    return String.class; 

}

public int getColumnCount() {
    return 4;
}

public String getColumnName(int column) {
    int x=0;
    if (column == x++) {
        return Texts.TableColumn.ID;
    } else if (column == x++) {
        return Texts.TableColumn.NAME;
    } else if (column == x++) {
        return Texts.TableColumn.CREATOR;
    } else if (column == x++) {
        return Texts.TableColumn.CREATED;
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Now my first attempt was to use constants for the index so I can directly read which column is meant (no widt, text, etc.) Example:

```
exampleTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(Constants.EXPL_TAB_COL_ID).setPreferredWidth(50);
```

However this has the negative side effect, that I have to use the Table name in the constant-name as for example the column ID can appear in multiple tables at different positions. The next attempt was to solve the problem by using Enums which actually worked for the original use-case of replacing the indeices with "Constants/Enums" for the readability:

```
exampleTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(TAB_EXPL.ID.ordinal()).setPreferredWidth(50);
```

However as the optimal solution would solve all the problems at once my goal is to find like this:

```
    for (TAB_EXPL col : TAB_EXPL.values()) {
       exampleTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(col.getIndex()).setPreferredWidth(col.getPreferredWidth);
    }

public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {

    if (columnIndex == TAB_EXPL.ID.getIndex()) {
        return Integer.class;
    } else if (columnIndex == TAB_EXPL.CREATED.getIndex()) {
        return Date.class;
    }
    return String.class; 

}

public int getColumnCount() {
    return TAB_EXPL.values().length;
}

public String getColumnName(int column) {
    for (TAB_EXPL col : TAB_EXPL.values()) {
        return col.getName();
    }
}
```

It doesn't matter if it's a class, enum or record it should just solve the problem. I also tried an approach with the EnumMap type in combination with a record however I failed when I tried to use multiple arguments(Record is defined with int Index, String name) in the put() method of the EnumMap. Also the put()-Method has to be called in a constructor or another method which makes the enum/constant attempt useless:

```
eMap.put(TAB_EXPL.ID, (0, "Id"));
```

Hope this helps to understand the problem and that someone can help me.

**EDIT2 SOLUTION:** I found a solution myself, however it is not exactly the one I searched and it does only work for Java version 9+. Here is an example in case someone has a similar problem or any additional ideas:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.EnumMap;

public class HelloWorld {
    public enum TAB_EXPL{ID,DATE,USER};
    public enum TAB_ATT{ID,NAME,STATE};
    public static void main(String[] args) {


    class RecordTableColumn {
        
        private final int index;
        private final String name;
        private final int colWidth;
    
        public RecordTableColumn(int index, String name, int colWidth) {
            this.index = index;
            this.name = name;
            this.colWidth = colWidth;
        }
    
        public int getIndex() {
            return index;
        }
    
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        
        public int getColWidth() {
            return colWidth;
        }
    }

    EnumMap<TAB_EXPL, RecordTableColumn> TabExpl = new EnumMap<>(Map.ofEntries(
        Map.entry(TAB_EXPL.ID, new RecordTableColumn(0, "Id", 10)),
        Map.entry(TAB_EXPL.DATE, new RecordTableColumn(1, "Date", 30)),
        Map.entry(TAB_EXPL.USER, new RecordTableColumn(2, "User", 100))
        ));

    EnumMap<TAB_ATT, RecordTableColumn> TabAtt = new EnumMap<>(Map.ofEntries(
        Map.entry(TAB_ATT.ID, new RecordTableColumn(0, "Id", 10)),
        Map.entry(TAB_ATT.NAME, new RecordTableColumn(1, "Name", 100)),
        Map.entry(TAB_ATT.STATE, new RecordTableColumn(2, "State", 50))
        ));

    System.out.println("Table Example:");
    for (TAB_EXPL col : TAB_EXPL.values()) {
        System.out.println("Index: " + TabExpl.get(col).getIndex());
        System.out.println("Name: " + TabExpl.get(col).getName());
        System.out.println("Column Width: " + TabExpl.get(col).getColWidth());
    }  
    System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Table Att:");
    for (TAB_ATT col : TAB_ATT.values()) {
        System.out.println("Index: " + TabAtt.get(col).getIndex());
        System.out.println("Name: " + TabAtt.get(col).getName());
        System.out.println("Column Width: " + TabAtt.get(col).getColWidth());
    }  
        
}
```

}

Comment: off-topic recommendation: don't store dynamic data (like users) in an enum - use the enum as a property of the users and store them in instances of a normal class

Comment: What are you trying to model here? The data here doesn't make a lot of sene to me just by looking at it.

Comment: It’s certainly possible to obtain the result that you want, and perhaps even in some elegant way, who knows? Before we can guide you, you need to explain your real goal.

Comment: Added the original idea as edit I hope it's formulated in an understandable way

Comment: @buec95 imho that still doesn't explain why you want to use enums and not regular classes.

Comment: My idea was to make an enum however I am also open for a regular class solution

Comment: What was your appeal to enums? What did they do that a normal class didn't for you? (Auto-complete names, constants, ....?)

Comment: The first attempt was to use constants for the index of the tablecolumns but as this would lead to a high number of constants and names (Some tables might have the same column but at different index) I choose the Enum as this would be sufficent for this usecase. However now the goal is to solve all at once I just stayed at the enum solution as it was suitable for the original usecase.

Comment: As said by Sweeper, your example doesn’t make any sense at all. Why is `Switzerland.ID` associated with `"Hans"`, `Switzerland.NAME` associated with `"Jan"` and `Switzerland.STATE` with `"Fritz"`? On a technical level, each `enum` constant does already have a name and an ordinal number, so if you declare `enum Person { Paul, Jan, Jack }`, there is already `Person.Paul.name() == "Paul"`, `Person.Paul.ordinal() == 0`, `Person.Jan.name() == "Jan"`, `Person.Jan.ordinal() == 1`, `Person.Jack.name() == "Jack"`, and `Person.Jack.ordinal() == 2`. But as said by SIMULATAN, persons are not constant.

Comment: The names and countries are just an example. The original use-case is the one mentioned in the edit section. I need an enum/class per table where each element in the enum/class describes one column and has attributes like index, name, width and similar.

Comment: As said, name and index are implied when you keep the constant name in sync with the column name and declare the constants in the intended order. Still, if you don’t need special `enum` features like `EnumMap`/`EnumSet`, etc., you’re probably better off using a `record ColumnDescription(String name, int index, int width, …) {}` and some explicitly declared `static final ColumnDescription …` fields. Or just `static final List<ColumnDescription> TABLE_XYZ_COLUMNS = List.of(…);`

Comment: That sounds good could you provide me a code example as I am not quite sure as far as I see the record class does not solve my problem as I have to create one variable for one column: So I have to include the table name in the variable name as for example the column "ID" could appear as first column in one table but as 3rd in another table. Do I miss something?

Comment: It depends on how you actually want to use these declarations. As said, you can have a declaration like `static final List<ColumnDescription> TABLE_ABC_COLUMNS = List.of(new ColumnDescription("ID"), new ColumnDescription("FOO")), TABLE_XYZ_COLUMNS = List.of(new ColumnDescription("ID"), new ColumnDescription("BAR"));` where table names are implied by the variable name holding the list and the column indices are implied by the position inside the list. You can also make this information explicit. It all depends on which actual operations you have to support.

Comment: The whole point of an enum is to have typesafe constants in your code base. For example, the compiler can detect if cases are uncovered in a `switch`. Creating enums dynamically doesn't make any sense to me. I'd think Records or plain classes would fit better. Maybe you should add more details to your question regarding what you tried with an interface and how it didn't work.

Comment: An initialization block might be helpful here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html

Answer (score 1):

The primary benefit of enums is type safe constants. If you have columns of many different tables mixed into one enum, you're losing out on type safety.

But enums can implement interfaces. And we can define an interface that all our "table-definition" enums should implement like this:

```
/**
 * Interface for enums that define a table. Should not be implemented by non-enum classes.
 */
public interface TableDefinition<T extends Enum<T>> {
    int getPreferredWidth();
    Class<?> getColumnClass();
}
```

Note that this interface *could* be implemented outside of an enum (there's no way in the type system that I know of to *force* an interface to only be implemented using `enum`), but we really only want enums.

Then we'll define a method like this somewhere (it should *probably* be a non-static method of `ColumnModel`, but I'll pretend you can't change that class for some reason):

```
static <T extends Enum<T> & TableDefinition<T>> void applyPreferredWidth(ColumnModel cm, Class<T> clazz) {
    for (T column : clazz.getEnumConstants()) {
        cm.getColumn(column.ordinal()).setPreferredWidth(column.getPreferredWidth());
    }
}
```

Now *this method* (and it's magic type parameter) ensures that the class passed to it references a class that's *both* and `enum` *and* implements our interface. This means we can use `enum` methods like `ordinal()` (which we'll just interpret as the column index) and our own methods like `getPreferredWidth()`.

Now an implementation of this enum could simply look like this:

```
public enum ExampleTable implements TableDefinition<ExampleTable> {
    ID(Integer.class, 50),
    NAME(String.class, 200),
    CREATOR(String.class, 150),
    CREATED(Instant.class, 100);

    private final Class<?> columnClass;
    private final int preferredWidth;

    ExampleTable(Class<?> columnClass, int preferredWidth) {
        this.columnClass = columnClass;
        this.preferredWidth = preferredWidth;
    }

    @Override
    public int getPreferredWidth() {
        return preferredWidth;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass() {
        return columnClass;
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer. The thing is I don't want to mix multiple tables in one enum there should be one enum/class for each table. I'm not sure if I understand your solution correctly but as far as I see an enum with the following constructor would have the same outcome with code that is simpler `ExampleTable(int index, String name, int colWidth). Logically including the getter methods for the parameters. My goal would be that I don't have to declare the mentioned constructor and getters for each enum(talbe).

Comment: You can't really get rid of those. This is about as little code duplication as possible. You could *either* generate those enums from some source at build time, or don't use `enum`  at all and create some records (or plain old classes) and read the configuration from some file/resource at runtime (but you lose the "one-type-is-one-table" association, which may or may not be ideal).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to write constructer and getter method. You can try lombok.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.26</version>
        </dependency>
```

And you can write enum like this.

```
package com.example;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;

public class EnumClass {

    @AllArgsConstructor
    @Getter
    public enum TableA {
        ID(Integer.class, 50);

        private final Class<?> aClass;
        private final Integer width;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class<?> aClass = TableA.ID.getAClass();
        Integer width = TableA.ID.getWidth();
    }
}
```

But you still need to write fields...

Comment: this literally defeats the point(s) of using enums.